# How to prevent formatting in XText

Tags: grammar, xtext

I have create xtext project. I haven't any Format class, but some default formatting is produced when I press ctrl + f.

In what way I can to prevent formatting? I suggest that I need to override formatter class, but in what way I can to produce this class? Or, maybe I can to prevent default formatting in the project settings?

Regards,
Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

you can either simply "create" the class

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    def Class<? extends IFormatter2> bindIFormatter2() {
        Formatter2NullImpl
    }

    def void configureFormatterPreferences(Binder binder) {
        binder.bind(IPreferenceValuesProvider).annotatedWith(FormatterPreferences).to(FormatterPreferenceValuesProvider);
    }

}

class Formatter2NullImpl implements IFormatter2 {

    override format(FormatterRequest request) {
        return #[]
    }

}

@FinalFieldsConstructor
class MyDslUiModule extends AbstractMyDslUiModule {

    override Class<? extends IContentFormatterFactory> bindIContentFormatterFactory() {
        return org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.formatting2.ContentFormatterFactory;
    }
}
```

or configure the workflow to do so

```
language = StandardLanguage {
    ...
    formatter = {
        generateStub = true
    }
    ...
}
```

and edit the generated class